# Save GIF files to Pictures folder?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia

Nokia Cinemagraph is able to save gif files to Pictures folder on the device. However XNA MediaLibrary class allows to save only JPEG files there.

How they are able to save gif files? Is there a new class in WP8 that let's you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got reply from Justin Angel (@JustinAngel) that those APIs are not exposed to the public.

Answer (score 2):

Nokia Cinemagraph doesn't exactly save GIF files in the Pictures folder, it actually stores a JPG photo along with a link to data stored in the local folder of the app.

This is done by using the new [**Rich media extensibility**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) functionality introduced with  Windows Phone 8.

> Rich media apps incorporate data from the local folder or the web to
>   provide a unique experience for viewing or editing the images they
>   have captured.

Comment: Oliver, I dont think this is entirely true. Here is what I see in Camera Roll when I plug my Lumia to PC: http://screencast.com/t/xxrugozYuutO